# Changing the URL and not reloading a page (this time without a url fragment)

Tags: ajax, browser, html, pretty-urls

Just wondering as to how did Google code this website without it reloading the website when the page AND url are changed.

Take a look and go from page to page.
http://www.20thingsilearned.com/

I've done a similar technique using a # hash change operation (with use of by the onhashchange event) to achieve the same result, however, this technique is far more cleaner.

Is this a chrome-specific feature? Or do all HTML5-enabled browsers support it? Or is there some complex combination of frames that are used together?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How does this site change the URL of the browser without changing pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222081/how-does-this-site-change-the-url-of-the-browser-without-changing-pages) as noted by Ranhiru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ this question

[How does this site change the URL of the browser without changing pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222081/how-does-this-site-change-the-url-of-the-browser-without-changing-pages)